# Ignore validation on soft deleted models

Tags: yii2

I have `user` table. I created a form with 3 fields:

- Username
- phonenumber
- status

The first two fields are unique. Model rules for those fields look like this:

```
[['Username', 'phonenumber'], 'required'],
[['Username', 'phonenumber'], 'unique'],
```

I use soft deletion, so when record is deleted, it actually stays in database but status value will change to `0`.

The problem is, if I add a record with existing username it shows an error message like "already added". I need to ignore validation if `username` have a status with value `0`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `filter` property of `UniqueValidator`

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...

        ['username', 'unique', 'filter' => ['<>', 'status', 0]];

        ...
    ];
}
```

It's better to declare constant instead of `0` (something like `const STATUS_DELETED = 0`) and user it as `self::STATUS_DELETED` inside of `User` class. Also you can use `!=` instead of `<>`.

The last recommendation will be to use `username` instead of `Username` to follow convention of naming database table columns.

Read more about ways of declaring `filter` in [official docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-uniquevalidator.html#$filter-detail).

The ways of setting `filter` condition as array is described [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-queryinterface.html#where%28%29-detail).

Comment: wat is the use of <> in filter array

Comment: It means `not equal`.

Comment: Updated the answer with information about specifying array in `filter`.

Comment: "The last recommendation will be to use Username" - did you mean "username"?

Comment: in yii2 is any widget for bulkdelete the records?

Answer (score -1):

You can use your own function to decide the given username already exists in active status or not. Use this function in "when" property of your unique validation rule.

Have a look :

```
public function rules()
{
    $check = function($model) { 
    $existActiveUser = User::model()->findByAttributes(array("username"=>$model->username,"status"=>1));
    if($existActiveUser)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
};
return [
    ['Username', 'phonenumber'], 'required'],
    [['Username','phonenumber'],'unique','when'=>$check],
}
```

Comment: Yes, but when the special property exists exactly for that, it doesn't make sense. Also your code is for Yii1.

Comment: yes you are right "filter" provides the exact functionality, hence no need to make function. Thnks